# Pasuk about community service

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, tzibur-community

I'm looking for a pasuk to pay tribute to a couple being honored for their service to both my local community and the greater Jewish community. Does anyone have one I can use?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please consider editing [your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2414/user2414) to give yourself a name, unless you have a special attachment to the number 2414. You could make this question more answerable by adding in some criteria that would help identify an ideal pasuk for your needs. Finally, I hope you'll poke around and find other information here that interests you, perhaps starting with our 58 other questions about [tag:tzibur-community].

Comment: The following is based on *B'reishis* 33:18-20 (it's not the plain meaning of the verses, so I'm not posting as an answer): When Ya'akov arrived in Shechem, he established a currency for them, constructed public roads, and built public bathhouses (*Shabbos* 33b). As Rashi (ad loc.) points out, when Yaakov encamped in this new locale, he also enhanced it (the Hebrew words for "encamp" and "beautify" share the same root); when he purchased land, he also improved it ("purchase" and "improve" share the same root in Hebrew). Only in the following verse does Ya'akov set up an altar for worship.

Answer (score 1):

[תהלים: כב. כג.
אספרה שמך לאחי בתוך קהל אהללך](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2622.htm)

[תהלים: לה. יח.
אודך בקהל רב בעם עצום אהללך](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2635.htm)

[תהלים: קז. לב.
וירוממוהו בקהל עם ובמושב זקנים יהללוהו](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26a7.htm)

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything you can think of that doesn't refer to Hashem?

Comment: You could improve this answer by translating the verses and indicating why you think they're fitting/ideal for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that their service involved tzedaka you can't get better than Isaiah 58:7-8.

> ז הלוא פרוס לרעב לחמך, ועניים מרודים תביא בית: כי-תראה ערום וכיסיתו, ומבשרך לא תתעלם. ח אז ייבקע כשחר אורך, וארוכתך מהרה תצמח; והלך לפניך צדקך, כבוד יהוה יאספך.
>   Will you not deal out your own bread to the hungry and bring [even] the unpleasant poor into your home: when you see the naked you cover them nor ignore your own family. (8) Then your light shall break like dawn, your success will be immediate, your reputation will preceed you and God Himself will be your reward. (My own slightly free translation.)

This passage speaks movingly about the virtue of charity and how someone who practices it properly is rewarded. Try Bava Basra (bavli) around 9b-10a for many good derashot.

Comment: You could improve this answer by translating the verses and indicating why you think they're fitting/ideal for this purpose.

Comment: Shkoyich. I already gave my +1, but much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[ברך ה' חילו ופועל ידיו תרצה](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0533.htm#11) is commonly used on dedication pages.

If you're looking for one that doesn't use G-d's name, [ברכה לראש משביר](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2811.htm#26) is also not uncommon on dedication pages. [ונתתי להם בביתי ובחומותי יד ושם טוב מבנים ומבנות שם עולם אתן לו](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1056.htm#5) also works.

I believe that I have seen all three of these on Oz VeHadar dedication pages.

Comment: You could improve this answer by translating the verses and indicating why you think they're fitting/ideal for this purpose.